# Renaming the label of the Title textfield

Tags: entities

Adding new fields allows you to specify the label of the field but the Title field does not. In fact, it just sits there on top acting all high and mighty. I just want to change the label of Title to something like `Your name` but retain the machine name. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to Content type, you will have a list of content types of your site. Under Operations click on edit  for the content type you want to change the title.  Under `Submission form  settings` you can change the "Title field label"

Answer (score 4):

Use **themename_preprocess_field** in template.php file in theme folder.

```
function themename_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) { 

    if($element['#field_name'] == 'field_xyz') {
      $variables['label'] = "your label name";
    } 

}
```